# How do I save my player object positions through different scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Hello I am completely new to C# and programing/game development in general, I've been working on making a 2d game on unity, the game is mainly inspired by hollow knight and I've come across a small problem I haven't been able to fix by myself, the problem is that when my character goes between rooms(scenes) it will always spawn in the start of the room which basically means that it will spawn where it first spawned when it got into the room instead of where I want it to spawn, at the end of the room where the collision detector object to switch scenes is.

I tried using PlayerPrefs through a tutorial I've seen on YouTube however I wasn't able to implement it to my situation/code, I tried going through a thread with a similar problem here in stack Overflow but I still wasn't able to implement the solutions that were written into my code probably because I didn't have a good enough understanding of what I was reading as I'm generally inexperienced in coding.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to call the DontDestroyOnLoad() method in the object's Start() method.  That will prevent the object from being destroyed when you switch scenes, so you'll want to prevent a new player from spawning in the new level if you do this.  However, it would mean the original player object would remain active in its current position, which should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer by @Louis:

The basic idea is to have a separate class which you want to have **one single** static instance of.

In the `Awake` method of this class you would then:

1. Assign the instance via `instance = this`
2. As @Louis pointed out: Call `DontDestroyOnLoad(ObjThisClassIsAttachedTo)`

For a detailed explanation see this imo very ostensive tutorial by Unity: [Unity tutorial on data persistence between scenes](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/implement-data-persistence-between-scenes#634f8281edbc2a65c86270cb)

Answer (score 0):

`PlayerPrefs` has a different purpose. A lot of beginners make the mistake of using it for saving "sensitive" game data such position, inventory, gold and so on which makes it open to cheating since it's saved as clear text. Its purpose is to save game, app or player options, that is all, not to save scene data.

To save scene data you can either use a persistent object using `DontDestroyOnLoad()` or if you want persistent data (such as saving the position during a "Save Game" operation), you can serialize data (meaning saving all states on disk). To use that, check the `JsonUtility`.

This is all general talk and for best practice. Coming back to your case, you can have 2 approaches. One is indeed, using `DontDestroyOnLoad`, but since you know already know that the player uses the "door", you can also treat this simpler. One method is to hook `SceneManager.activeSceneChanged` which has the signature of `void ChangedActiveScene(Scene current, Scene next)`. Then you can use each scene incremently in the build settings, so that you know which scene ordering should behave as, thanks to their order in the list. What I mean is, for a game like the movie Home Alone, you can have the first scene at position 0 as the Living Room, 1 is Kitchen, 2 is Dining Room and so on. Then using the `activeSceneChanged` you can see which `buildIndex` you get from `current` and `next`, then just spawn the player at the correct door (either the start or end of the scene). For example, going from Living Room to Kitchen, since LR has the index of 1 and Kitchen has 2, you know that passing through the door will put the player at the start of the scene in the Kitchen. Then going back, you know that since the previous Scene was the Kitchen, he will now be at the end of Living Room, not the start. The advantage of this is you will have more control. If you have the spawn points `GameObjects` named "StartPos" and "EndPos" then you can simply check `if (current.buildIndex > next.buildIndex) to know you'll need to spawn the player at the position of the EndPos GameObject since you know he is going "back".

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, I tried using DontDestroyOnLoad but after about 3 hours of trying to make everything work  and like 5 youtube videos I gave up on it since I just couldn't make it work which I'm sure is because of my own incompetence so what I'm saying is if its not too much of a bother could you explain to me in the simplest way you can or write me an example of code of how to do it which is pretty much what you already wrote but I couldn't understand exactly how to implement anything in my code :( once again sorry for the trouble and thanks a lot

Comment: There are lots of free save systems on the asset store, until you learn to create your own. You could examine their code to learn the various ways. https://assetstore.unity.com/?free=true&q=save%20system&orderBy=1